# Conversion of numbers of type float in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, floating-point, data-conversion

In my task I had number 12.7 that is represented in septenary number system (base = 7) and I need to convert this number to system with base 11.
I think I should firstly convert this number to decimal system and only after that to system with base 11.

```
base1 = 7;
base2 = 11;
num = 12.3;
str_num = num2str(12.3);
num_dec = typecast(int16(base2dec(str_num,base1)), 'float');
```

I got an error as a result.

```
??? Error using ==> base2dec at 41
String 12.3 contains characters which cannot be converted to base 7.
```

Is there any solution for this problem? How can I convert such kind of numbers (floating-point numbers) using matlab?

Comment: `help base2dec` --> `base2dec(S,B) converts the string number S of base B into its decimal (base 10) equivalent.  B must be an integer between 2 and 36. S must represent a non-negative integer value.` this is why it didn't work: `num` is not an integer. You might have to do it manually.

Comment: Also: [see this](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/conversion-of-floating-point-numbers-in-matlab/)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I`m not quite sure how to do this manually.

Comment: For instance: first you can determine the largest decimal (septimal?) using `floor(log7(num))=floor(ln(num)/ln(7))`. Then with decreasing digits you can compute how much of `7^n` fits into the remainder of `num`. Once your remainder is less than `tol`, you stop. Then do the reverse to convert to base 11 manually. There's probably a smarter way but I'm only used to base 10.

Comment: Note that in my previous comment you probably need `fix` instead of `floor` to treat negative numbers properly... So: when you say "*In my task I had number...*", do you mean a homework? I wouldn't want to spoil that for you.